# vim - special characters

Tags: vim

I compiled vim 7.3.206 on Mac OS X 10.6.7. When I enter special characters, such as `Ü` or `ß`, it doesn't work but gets automatically changed to a mess like `?~\` or `?~_'.

Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found [something that might help](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/utf-problems-with-regular-vim-not-macvim-on-os-x-tp1214073p1214076.html) assuming you've set up UTF-8 corrctly.